# Registered custom block not showing up

Tags: 7, blocks

I tried to register two custom block in my custom_blocks module with the following code.

```
function custom_blocks_block_info(){
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['featured_items'] = array(
    'info' => t('Featured Items'),
    'status' => TRUE
  );
  $blocks['workflow_illustration'] = array(
    'info' => t('How it works'),
    'status' => TRUE
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function custom_blocks_block_view($delta = ''){
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'featured_items':
      $block['content'] = featured_items();
      break;
    case 'workflow_illustration':
      $block['content'] = workflow_chart();
      break;
  }
  return $block;    
}
```

But the    problem is 'Featured Items' block is shown in the block administer page. But the 'How it Works' block is not shown (may be not registered :?) in the block administer page.

I tried deactivating the module >> clear drupal cache >> clear browser cache (?) >> activate the module again.

Still the 'Featured Block' is the only block showing up. Please help me to get my block accessible via block administer page.

Comment: May be the problem is in "workflow_chart()" function have you checked it?

Comment: No @Enxebre both featured_items() and workflow_chart() returning simple html output. something like return '<div class="class"><span>Something</span></div>";

Comment: i suggest to try with a full inline content for testing

Comment: The blocks should still be listed in the block administer page regardless of what is in the block content. I copied your block_info() function into a custom module and tried it, and the two blocks show up in my blocks administer page. So the question is what is different on your drupal installation

Comment: Is what you've got in the question an identical copy-paste of your code? If it is, I'd suspect you've made some changes to core/contrib modules, or have dev/alpha/beta versions of modules that mess with blocks in some way. The code in your question, copied and pasted exactly, works fine for me too. Both blocks show up.

Comment: Could you check with another key for workflow_illustration?

Comment: ... I copied everything into a new module again. Got it working now. I don't know where I made the mistake. Finally I got my thing working now. Thousands of hearty thanks to you all genius.

Comment: Please let me know the answer for one more question.. When I add $block['subject']. The subject is always appear as the heading of the block. What I can do if I don't want any title to be appeared. But @Molot said it is not a good practise avoiding $block['subject'] ...

Comment: Add <none> in the title of the block in the block/region association

Comment: @pico34 Found it. Thank you anyway. Thank you all once again

Answer (score 1):

First, try to provide `$block['subject']`. Second,  omit `status` in hook_block_info implementation, it may cause problems when there is no region assigned.

Comment: added $block['subject'] and removed the 'status' now hook_block_info just has 'info' => ''

but still it's not working @Mołot

Comment: Molot is on the right track - hook_block_info needs to have $block["info"] set. This is the administrative title of the block. In hook_block_view, you need to set $block["subject"] and $block["content"]

Answer (score 1):

Double check if:

1. Module is enabled.
2. Module is not duplicated and `system` table points to the right file:

   ```
   drush sqlq "SELECT * FROM system WHERE name = 'foo'"
   ```
3. You cleared all caches (in *Development/Performance*).

#### Troubleshooting

- Check if `hook_block_info()` is called after clearing caches (add `exit('foo');` to see if that break the site). If it's not called, then:

  - check for typos,
  - restart external caches (such as `memcached` or `redis`) if in use,
  - restart Apache server (it could be `OPCache`/`XCache`)
- use `drush` to see if the hook is called:

  ```
  drush cc all
  ```
- install `drush_extras` (via `drush dl drush_extras`) and check if the block is on the list when running from CLI:

  ```
  drush block-show | less +/my_block
  ```
- if you've Devel enabled, try load the block at `/devel/php` and check if does exist:

  ```
  print_r(block_load('foomodule', 'foodelta'), TRUE);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I remove status from info block.
disable the my module and click uninstall tab and did uninstall for same module.
after disabling the module it comes in uninstall list.
clear cache and it's working now.

changed  code:

```
function module_block_info() {
 $blocks = array();
 $blocks['hnavigation'] = array(
   'info' => t('Homepage Naviagation'),
 );
 $blocks['hslider'] = array(
   'info' => t('Homepage Banner Slider'),
 );

 return $blocks;
}
```

Previous code :

```
function module_block_info() {
 $blocks = array();
 $blocks['hnavigation'] = array(
   'info' => t('Homepage Naviagation'),
   'status'=>1,
 );
 $blocks['hslider'] = array(
   'info' => t('Homepage Banner Slider'),
   'status'=>1,

 );

 return $blocks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're an eejit like me this can occur when you name a custom block something which matches a flagged #id tag in an adblocker.