# Custom Block from module not showing on front-end?

Tags: 8, blocks

I have created a custom block in a custom module. Sometimes the block appears correctly, and sometimes the block doesn't appear. The same happens when I clear the cache.

The `build()` method returns the following value.

```
return [
  '#markup' => $html,
  '#cache' => array('max-age' => 0)
];
```

I also tried with the following code.

```
return (array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#cache' => array('max-age' => 0),
  '#markup' => $html,
));
```

These are the other methods of the block.

```
protected function blockAccess(AccountInterface $account) {
  return AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'access content');
}

public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $config = $this->getConfiguration();

  return $form;
}

public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $this->configuration['custom_block_settings'] = $form_state->getValue('custom_block_settings');
}
```

Comment: From the given code I cannot see anything producing this (I did try to reproduce it myself) What Drupal version do you use? Who is the user? (anonymous, authenticated, a certain role, etc?) What caching modules do you use? Do you use the Masquerade module, etc?

Comment: Drupal version: 8.4.4
No cache module is being used rather cache is disabled.
User Role: Any

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it on a clean install with only the block?

Comment: I think you can try these steps to make it work. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85490/registered-custom-block-not-showing-up

Comment: How are you clearing cache? Can you test in a different browser you haven't tried yet? What's the result you get?

Comment: @brotherperes I am clearing the cache normal way i.e. using Flush all cache in Admin toolbar, I have used chrome, safari and firefox browsers, but no luck.

Comment: What's the purpose of `$config = $this->getConfiguration();` in blockForm()?

Comment: When exactly the block appears and when disappears?

Comment: Just to confirm, that the $html contains only string not renderable array. Also try calling `parent::blockSubmit($form, $form_state);` in blockSubmit function. Can you also share entire code from your block class php file, that will help debug more easily.

Comment: Try splitting the problem up by replacing $html with a constant string.  If this always shows up, it's probably how or what you generate for $html.  If it still persists with a constant string, it's something with your setup.  Maybe an upstream alter on the block or a permission.  Also, make sure you don't have any 3rd party caching happening.  E.g. CloudFlare, NGinx, Varnish and the like.